# How to create a new textarea when the user uses shift+enter for the submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have some code like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 13){
        console.log(e)
        executeScript();
        //$document.createElement("#textarea");
        //if (error) {
        //    return false;
        //} if (correctly executed) {
        //    create new box
        //    return true;
        //}
        return false;
    }
})
```

The line $document.createElement("#textarea"); only expands a line, but I want to create another textarea when the user submits with shift+enter.

Also, to prohibit the user submitting multiple times and creating multiple unused textareas, could I focus on just the active textarea (where the cursor is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq1nbk91/)

You can get the ID of the the element from the event as:

> ```
> event.target.id
> ```

And it is easier to use Jquery to create a new text area.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 13){
        alert(e.target.id)
        //executeScript();
        var textArea = $('<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="four"></textarea>');
        $("#contnr").append(textArea);
        //$document.createElement("#textarea");
        //if (error) {
          //  return false;
        //} if (correctly executed) {
          //  create new box
           // return true;
        //}
        return false;
    }
})
```

I hope  it helps =]

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.createElement("textarea");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```